# Какую сетку лучше использовать?

Tags: css3, html5, bootstrap4, css-grid

Нужно сверстать вот такой блок, но я не могу понять что лучше использовать для правой части блока(картинки) при верстке. Bootstrap-grid, css-grid вроде не подойдут, так как разные по высоте ряды (могу ошибаться). Через что лучше это реализовать?[image: Блок]

Comment: можете попробовать расчиать размеры, пропорции картинок и на этих данных задать им правильные размеры, или поискать JS библиотеку для этого. Встречал подобную верстку в галереи на wordpress. Еще можно на bootstrap 4 с их flex, но придется думать о размерах картинок, полагаю

Comment: Сделал через флексбоксы)

Comment: значит таки бутстрап) хорошо :)

Answer (score 0):

Можно и без bootstrap на чистом css grid

```css
.grid-custom {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid-custom div:first-child {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
}

.grid-custom div:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 5;
}

.grid-custom div:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}

.grid-custom div:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 5;
}

.grid-custom div:last-child {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="grid-custom col-7">
        <div>
          <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1402787/pexels-photo-1402787.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="" width="100%">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1236701/pexels-photo-1236701.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="" width="100%" height="100%">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1402787/pexels-photo-1402787.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="" width="100%" height="100%">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1402787/pexels-photo-1402787.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="" width="100%" height="100%">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1402787/pexels-photo-1402787.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="" width="100%" height="120px">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```